# Maximum days to light candles

Tags: arrays, sorting, puzzle

You are given heights of n candles. First day you lit one candle Second day you   need to lit two candles Third day you need to lit three candles till possible. After lighting candles the height of candles deduced by 1 each day.You can also extinguish any candle you want but only at the end of day. So you need to tell the maximum number number of days , you can carry on lighting the candles.

```
Example : there are three candles of heights {2 ,2 ,2 }  
Answer : 3  
1.You light first candle on day one. heights -> {1,2,2}  
2.You light second and third and extinguish first one . heights ->{1, 1,1}  
3.You light all the candles. heights -{0,0,0}
```

I found the solution on one blog as:

Sort the array.Start from the maximum each day we add an element and subtract the number of candles needed. So for 2,2,2

```
Day 1: 2-1 = 1 Day 2: 1+2-2 = 1 Day 3: 1+2-3 = 0  
Answer is: 3  
But for 1,1,1 this algorithm will fail as answer should be 2.
```

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: It can be done by sorting each day and take maximum elements but the time complexity would be O(N^2 LogN). I want to optimize it further.

Comment: Even if you use a self-sorting structure like heap, you will get `O(N^2 * logN)` complexity. It doesn't look like there is a math solution - it looks more like this problem is requiring a greedy algorithm. What is an upper bound of N?

Comment: Yeah you are right. Upper bound of N is not given. I was just trying to optimize it further by any greedy algorithm but this won't work everytime.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.  Maybe try https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

for first two days it lit 1 + 2 = 3 units of candles
after that 3 units/days.

```
So if you want to lit a candle for 5 days , total unit of candle must be = 3 unit (for two days) + 
(3 * 3) (for rest of three days)
= 12 unit,
so you either need 3 candles of 4 unit , or 4 candles of 3 unit or 6 candles of 2 unit or 12 candles of 1 unit.

Hence, if h = number of height and n = number of candles(must be greater than 2)
then your equation will be number of days = (((h * n) - 3)/3) + 2
= (h * n)/3 + 1
```

in (((h * n) - 3)/3) + 2, -3 is reduced for first two days(3 units) , because it is added as constant +2(days) in the equation.

this equation will only satisfy if number of candles is greater than or equal to 3.beaceuse if there is only one candle of infinity height, you can not lit it twice on second day.
so if n <= 2 number of days will be n;

```
So complete equation will be:

if n <= 2 : number of days = n;
if n > 2 : number of days = (h * n)/3 + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I presented this question to my students today and this is the solution I came up with. It runs in O(n) (really it is running in O(amount) time b/c the height is a non-factor here. You can never burn more days than you have candles b/c the at amount+1 day you won't have enough actual candles to burn even if you have enough candle pieces left.)

```
public static int getAmtOfBurnDays(int height, int amount){
    int totalDaysThatWhereBurned = 0;

    int totalPiecesLeft = height * amount;

    while (totalDaysThatWhereBurned < amount){

        if(totalPiecesLeft < 0) break;

        totalDaysThatWhereBurned++;

        totalPiecesLeft -= totalDaysThatWhereBurned;
    }

    return totalDaysThatWhereBurned;
}
```

Comment: You are taking height argument as an integer. Isn't that supposed to be an input array?

Comment: Good point! The answer I gave doesn't meet the question requirements.